# line split array on console?

Tags: c#, .net, string, version, string-parsing

lets take for example i have a string declared:

```
string master = "1.2.3.4";
```

which is in the form of:

`major.minor.project.build`

how do i get a string "major","minor","project" and "build" assigned separately from the string "master"?

I know we have to do line.split and this is what i have tried:

```
        string[] master = line.Split('.');
        string major = master[0];
        string minor = master[1];
        string project = master[2];
        string build = master[3];
```

Comment: I've edited this, because note he's using some "master" array variable so I guess he's not asking if he did it wrong but if there's other approaches to do so. I've added "master" variable declaration, because it seems he forgot to paste it in this code sample...

Comment: What needed as the result: separated strings or numbers?

Comment: separated strings with the different numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to split the string by `'.'` to get major, minor, build etc

```
string master = "1.2.3.4";
string [] arr = master.Split('.');

 string major = arr [0];         
string minor = arr [1];         
string project = arr [2];         
 string build = arr [3];
```

Comment: Have you really read this question? You're ansewring the same thing question's author suggested.........

Comment: No. The poster did not assign master.Split into another variable and was referencing master again.

Comment: I'm not agreed and this is why I edited his question. Check @Alex answer and you'll find other one understood he's looking for another approach :)

Comment: The question was unclear to me so I provided both the way to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case you can use `Version` class.

```
var master = "1.2.3.4";
var version = new Version(master);

var major = version.Major;
var minor = version.Minor;
var build = version.Build;
var revision = version.Revision;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like**

```
string master = "1.2.3.4";

string major = master.Split('.')[0];
string minor = master.Split('.')[1].;
string project = master.Split('.')[2];
string build = master.Split('.')[3];
```

**or**

```
string master = "1.2.3.4";
string [] arrayvar = master.Split('.');

 string major = arrayvar [0];         
string minor = arrayvar [1];         
string project = arrayvar [2];         
 string build = arrayvar [3];
```

Comment: First example will have too many unnecessary operations: on each line Split will create new array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

My humild opinion is I don't know what you find wrong in your approach.

I'm going to point you that this is the right way of doing this.

There're other situations where you'll need to identify parts of some text by using regular expressions because you want to validate that such input should be in some specific format or so. That's using regular expression match groups, but I believe you're doing right and any other approach would be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case, split is the best.

But in case you are exploring other options also ,You can use regex to split something like this :

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(master, "(\\.)");
```